# Exception while extracting substring from hive column

Tags: hive

I have one column "category" which contain data like this

`"Failed extract of third-party root list from auto update cab at: <http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab> with error: The data is invalid."`

I need to select url part in between `" < > "` sign of category column.
I have written a hive query -

```
select level,category,regexp_extract(category,'http://[^\>]*') AS url from event where level='Error';
```

I got an exception :

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201406122248_0014, Tracking URL = http://0.0.0.0:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201406122248_0014
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201406122248_0014
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2014-06-13 02:13:35,696 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-06-13 02:14:13,895 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201406122248_0014 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://0.0.0.0:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201406122248_0014
Examining task ID: task_201406122248_0014_m_000002 (and more) from job job_201406122248_0014

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_201406122248_0014_m_000000

URL:
  http://localhost.localdomain:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201406122248_0014&tipid=task_201406122248_0014_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"level":"Error","datetimes":"6/13/2014 9:24:05 AM","source":"Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2","eventid":4107,"task":"None","category":"\"Failed extract of third-party root list from auto update cab at: <http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab> with error: The data is invalid."}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused 

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

how to fix this?
Please help.

Comment: You could try clearing the `cache` and re-rerun...the command is `certutil -urlcache * delete`

Comment: Tried that command in hive, I got ParseException:cannot recognize input near 'certutil' '-' 'urlcache'

Comment: It's not a Hive command. In Windows, you could run it from `cmd`

Comment: Tried that as well still getting the same error :(

Comment: Did you mean that you ran the `certutil` command and then reran and it failed again? If so, then it's worth taking a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2328240) . You could try cleaning up the rest of the cache as mentioned there.

Comment: Got diffrent error :  RuntimeException org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot create directory /tmp/hive-cloudera/hive_2014-06-13_04-27-21_172_3943393305350870419-1. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 247 has reached the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 247. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 12 seconds.